# Generic Method with initialization of Set

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a generic method to combine sets.

```
public class CollectionsHelper {
    public static Set<?> combineSets(Set<?> set1, Set<?> set2){
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<?>() {{
            addAll(set1);
            addAll(set2);
        }});
    }
}
```

But I get the compile error:

> Wildcard type '?' cannot be instantiated directly

Comment: Or use Guava's `Sets.union()`.

Comment: I do not prefer using external libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generic type parameter instead of the wildcard:

```
public static <T> Set<T> combineSets(Set<T> set1, Set<T> set2)
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<T>() {{
        addAll(set1);
        addAll(set2);
    }});
}
```

On second thought, I wouldn't use an anonymous `HashSet` sub-class instance. I'd prefer:

```
public static <T> Set<T> combineSets(Set<T> set1, Set<T> set2)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<>(set1);
    set.addAll (set2);
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
}
```

Comment: @Code.IT Creating an instance of an anonymous sub-class of HashSet for no good reason makes no sense to me.

Comment: It originally was copied code of a static initialization for a private static final property :D I think you are right :D

Answer (score 2):

Your error is happening because the compiler can't guarantee that the `?` for the `Set<?>` that you're returning is a supertype of the `?` types in the two `Set<?>` arguments.

What you want is a generic method.  The type parameter needs to be a supertype of both the types that you've used in your set.  You could do it like this.

```
public static <E> Set<E> combineSets (Set<? extends E> set1, Set<? extends E> set2) {
    Set<E> toReturn = new HashSet<E>();
    toReturn.addAll(set1);
    toReturn.addAll(set2);
    return toReturn;
}
```

The `? extends E` part is important.  This says that `set1` and `set2` don't have to be `Set<E>` - they could be sets of any subclass of `E`.  Type inference will then make `E` into the lowest superclass of the two types.

If you really need this to be an unmodifiable set, then change the last line to

```
return Collections.unmodifiableSet(toReturn);
```

Comment: This does not contain Collections.unmodifiableSet();

Comment: Do you need it to?  It's not clear from your question.  You can always make the last line into `return Collections.unmodifiableSet(toReturn);`.

Comment: Just commenting, that it does not equals the same result of the expected in my question

Comment: Well, I answered your question as stated.  If you have additional requirements,  you need to ask your question more clearly.  Anyway, I've edited it now, to encompass the additional requirement.

Comment: Mentioning of PECS actually makes this a better answer than the accepted one